# How do I effectively link javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link a javascript file to my html that will display a digital clock

I've checked online and used the script tag as it was said but the changes don't show on my web page, I need help please

```
html
 <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset=>
        <title>About Me</title>
        <link href=".\main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
```

java script

```
function updateClock(){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

    var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
    currentHours = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + ":" + timeOfDay;

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = currentTimeString;
};

//windows.onload=init;
```

Comment: You've put your code inside of a function. You need to *invoke* that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a number of problems.

First, in your head, either set the charset value to something or get rid of it. The problem I'm referring to is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset=>`.

Second, the html needs to load before your javascript is called. To fix this, put your script at the bottom, right before your `</body>` tag or change your `<body>` to `<body onload="updateClock()">`. If you do it the first way, make sure to *call* your function; otherwise, nothing will happen.

Finally, you need to add a div tag or something with the id "clock"; otherwise your `document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML` won't be able to do anything.

Total Summary:

```js
    function updateClock(){
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
        var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

        currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
        currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

        var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
        currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
        currentHours = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

        var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + ":" + timeOfDay;

        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = currentTimeString;
    };
```

```html
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>About Me</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="updateClock()">
        <div id="clock"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML, try to put `onLoad="updateClock()"` in the `body` tag or a container tag to call your clock method from JS.

Like this,

`<div onLoad="updateClock()" class="clock"></div>`

**OR**

```
<body onLoad="updateClock()">
....
</body>
```

This can be done with *any* tag.

**Full example here:**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Comment: Note that this example has `setTimeout` which will make the clock "tick". The user might want to add that into their function and call it from the body, or simply run the script with `window.onload = ...`